# How can I set an ExpressionEngine session variable from PHP?

Tags: php, session-variables, expressionengine

ExpressionEngine version is **1.6.8** and **NOT** upgradeable.

I would like to set a session variable in index.php and have that variable available to javascript in an ExpressionEngine template.

I have already tried using $_SESSION and global $SESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [session_variables](http://www.putyourlightson.net/session-variables-plugin) plugin allows this